# HttpWorkerRequest.GetBytesRead() always returns 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, ihttpmodule

Anyone know why HttpWorkerRequest.GetBytesRead() always returns 0, even during and after a file upload?  Would like to use this method to build a progress bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpworkerrequest.getbytesread(v=VS.90).aspx

so probably this only returns this on a certain moment in the pipeline, but as stated by MS I would not try to use it since it's not supported ...